# Why do my sudo commands work with ansible but not with ansible-playbook?

Tags: azure, ansible

I'm experimenting with running Ansible scripts to set up Microsoft Azure VMs and for some reason I can run sudo commands through 'ansible', but can't run them through 'ansible-playbook'.

As an example, I expect that the following command should fail without specifying the --become and --ask-become-pass flags, and it does:

```
[user@localhost AnsibleScripts]$ ansible -i azure_rm.yml test_hosts -a "touch /testFile" -u testuser

testVM_da13 | FAILED | rc=1 >>
touch: cannot touch ‘/testFile’: Permission deniednon-zero return code
```

But I can get it working by adding the '-b' and '-K' arguments:

```
[user@localhost AnsibleScripts]$ ansible -i azure_rm.yml test_hosts -a "touch /testFile" -u testuser -b -K
SUDO password:

testVM_da13 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
```

Now, when I try to run the same command configured in a playbook I get the following output:

```
[user@localhost AnsibleScripts]$ ansible-playbook -i azure_rm.yml install_test.yml -u testuser -b -K
SUDO password:

PLAY [Install and configure test] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [testVM_da13]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Sorry, try again.\n[sudo via ansible, key=******************************] password: \nsudo: 1 incorrect password attempt\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}
```

The contents of install_test.yml is:

```
---
- name: Install and configure test
  hosts: test_hosts
  connection: local

  tasks:
   - name: test
     shell: touch /testFile
...
```

Does anyone have any suggestions about how I could get my sudo commands working through ansible-playbook?

Thanks for taking the time to look through my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`connection: local` means `execute every command on the localhost`.

Remove it from your playbook and try again.

Comment: Wow, that's embarrassing. I spent hours looking into why it wasn't working. The answer was staring me in the face all along! Thanks for your help!